# Avoid ngOnChanges until ngOnInit is completed in Angular

Tags: angular

**Scenario :** I have two components `Parent` and `Child`. Both components have some API calls being done in `ngOnInit`. Child component has `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook.
On page load based on certain conditions I'm triggering child's `ngOnChanges` from Parent component by changing the @Input parameter being passed to `Child`.

**Issue :** Child component's `ngOnChanges` is being triggered from `Parent` component before the Child component's `ngOnInit` is completed.

How to avoid this ??

Comment: You could use a service to store the data, and then when everything is ready have the service set the data on the parent and/or child.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from parent component once your ngOninit api call completes you will be updating the input variable for child component.

You can check a condition in child components ngOnchanges :

```
ngOnChanges(changes: import("@angular/core").SimpleChanges): void {
    //reLoad: Boolean type input parameter comming from parent component
    if (changes['reLoad'] && (changes['reLoad'].previousValue !== changes['reLoad'].currentValue)) {
      if (changes['reLoad'].currentValue) {
        //Call load method of child component
        this.childApiLoad();
      }
    }
  }
```

- It's a default behavior of Angular component, ngOnChanges lifecycle hook will invoke first and than ngOnInit.
  https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: But that will be loading API calls twice. Once inside the ngOnint and once in ngOnChanges.

Comment: Actually due to this condition(if (changes['reLoad'] && (changes['reLoad'].previousValue !== changes['reLoad'].currentValue)), it will not satisfy for the first time. When a components instantiated by default the ngOnChanges fired automatically and the above condition will not satisfied hence the load will not happen

Answer (score 0):

Try `ngDoCheck()` instead of `ngOnChanges()`. It could resolve your problem because it is triggered after `ngOnInit()`.

Docs here: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence